# Install TensorFlow & Tensorboard from source

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorboard

I want to install Tensorflow (CPU)(py 3.6) for windows, my company uses a proxy, so i can't install through pip, i have to build it from source.
I unzipped tensorflow/tensorboard/protobuf.tar.gz in my Anaconda3 folders.

When i use the setup.py files, it occurs that i need  tensorboard for installing tensorflow, and i need tensorflow for installing tensorboard.

So i don't know how to proceed for installing Tensorflow without using dependencies from pypi.org.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use pip with proxy. I was struggling with company proxy too and that was the solution for me:
Run a command prompt as administrator and type the following:

pip install --proxy http://username:password@proxy_url:port tensorflow

(this will install the latest CPU version of tensorflow)

This should work.

Comment: Thanks, it builds with the dependencies already located and compiled in the repo. My proxy situation is still there because i don't know which port is open, however i can use the new package.

Comment: If you would like to you can try to figure out your proxy as it is described here: https://superuser.com/a/346376

Answer (score 0):

**Installing with Anaconda**

follow steps to install TensorFlow in an Anaconda environment:

1. [Download](https://www.continuum.io/downloads) and install Anaconda.

Create a conda environment named tensorflow to run a version of Python by invoking the following command:

```
$ conda create -n tensorflow
```

Activate the conda environment by issuing the following command:

```
 $ source activate tensorflow

(tensorflow)$  # Your prompt should change 

(tensorflow)$ pip install --ignore-installed --upgrade tfBinaryURL
```

where tfBinaryURL is the URL of the [TensorFlow Python package](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_linux#the_url_of_the_tensorflow_python_package). For example, the following command installs the CPU-only version of TensorFlow for Python 2.7:

```
(tensorflow)$ pip install --ignore-installed --upgrade \ https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorflow-1.2.1-cp34-cp34m-linux_x86_64.whl
```

For detail  [offical link](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_linux#InstallingAnaconda)

Comment: Thanks for your help, i'm afraid conda leads to the same problem that pip, i have a HTTP connection error : 'ConnectionError(MaxRetryError(httpsConnectionPool.... Failed to establisg a new connection [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed' .